# How do I filter an unorderded list to display only selected items using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2DKh/17/) where I am trying to make it so that the items in an unordered list are visible only if the option selected in a drop down matches their class. List items may have multiple classes, but so long as at least one class matches, the item should be made visible.

The Javascript looks like this:

```
function showListCategories() {
    var selection = document.getElementById("listDisplayer").selectedIndex;
    var unHidden = document.getElementsByClassName(selection);
    for (var i = 0; i < unHidden.length; i++) {
        unHidden[i].style.display = 'visible';
    }
};
```

The idea is that it gets the current selection from the drop down, creates an array based on the matching classes, then cycles through each item and sets the CSS to be hidden on each one.

However, it's not working. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wroing?

Note that I haven't yet coded the "show all" option. I think I'll probably be able to figure that out once I have this first problem solved.

Comment: Your fiddle is not setup correctly, check console. And `display:visible` is not valid CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fiddle change load script `No wrap - in <head>`.

Just change your function like following

```
function showListCategories() {
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
   //above code to reset all lis if they are already shown

    var selection = document.getElementById("listDisplayer").value;
    lis = document.getElementsByClassName(selection);
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

and in `css` it should be `none` not `hidden`

```
.cats, .rats, .bats {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to show all `li` when `showAll` is selected, add `all` classes to all lis.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going on. First, your fiddle is not setup correctly, if you open the console you'll see:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showListCategories is not defined

This means that the function doesn't exist at the point you attach the event or that the function is out of scope, because by default jsFiddle will wrap your code in the `onLoad` event. To fix it you need to load the script as `No wrap - in <body>`.

Second, there's no such thing as a `display:visible` property in CSS. The property you want to toggle is `display:none` and `display:list-item`, as this is the default style of `<li>` elements.

Now, to make this work, it is easier if you add a common class to all items, let's say `item`, that way you can hide them all, and just show the one you want by checking if it has a certain class, as opposed to querying the DOM many times.  You should cache your selectors, it is not necessary to query every time you call the function:

```
var select = document.getElementById('listDisplayer');
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

function showListCategories() {
    var selection = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].className.indexOf(selection) > -1) {
            items[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        } else {
            items[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/E2DKh/28/

Answer (score 1):

You have many things wrong in your code and a wrong setting in the jsFiddle.  Here's a working version that also implements the "all" option:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Efc5/

```
function applyToList(list, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        fn(list[i], list);
    }
}

function hide(list) {
    applyToList(list, function(item) {
        item.style.display = "none";
    });
}

function show(list) {
    applyToList(list, function(item) {
        item.style.display = "block";
    });
}

function showListCategories() {
    var value = document.getElementById("listDisplayer").value;
    var itemList = document.getElementById("itemList");
    var items = itemList.getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (value === "all") {
        show(items);
    } else {
        // hide all items by default
        hide(items);
        show(itemList.getElementsByClassName(value));
    }
}
```

Changes made:

1. You have to fetch the `.value` of the select to see what the value was of the option that was picked.  You were using the `selectedIndex` which is just a number.
2. A common technique for displaying only a set of objects is to hide all of them, then show just the ones you want.  Since the browser only does one repaint for the entire operation, this is still visually seamless.
3. When finding items that match your class, you should be searching only the `<ul>`, not the entire document.  I added an id to that `<ul>` tag so it can be found and then searched.
4. To save code, I added some utility functions for operating on an HTMLCollection or nodeList.
5. Tests for the "all" option and shows them all if that is selected
6. Changed the jsFiddle to the Head option so the code is available in the global scope so the HTML can find your change handler function.
7. Switched style settings to `"block"` and `"none"` since `"visible"` is not a valid setting for `style.display`.

Answer (score 1):

First there is no property in Css like `display:hidden;` it should be `display: none;`

here is the solution please not that i am doing it by targeting id finished

Js function

```
    var selection = document.getElementById("listDisplayer");
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
selection.onchange = function () {
    var value = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value; // to get Value
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].className.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            list[i].style.display = "list-item";
        } else {
            list[i].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

css Code

```
    .cats, .rats, .bats {
    display: none;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E2DKh/30/)**